# monaco-editor tokenizer do not support "ignore case" regex

Tags: javascript, editor, monaco-editor

The `tokenizer` in `monaco-editor` do not seem to support 'ignore case' `i` flag in regex. Sample code below,

To replicate, you can paste this in [playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html) and try running yourself.

```
monaco.languages.register({ id: 'sample' });
monaco.languages.setMonarchTokensProvider('sample', {
    tokenizer: {
        root: [
            [/cmd1|cmd2/i, 'keyword']
        ]
    }
});

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    value: "cmd1 10\nCMD2 10",
    language: 'sample'
});
```

`cmd1` turns blue while `CMD2` do not.

Is this intentional? Is there a way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `ignoreCase:true` to the options should work.

[Editor Reference](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html)

```
monaco.languages.register({ id: 'sample' });
monaco.languages.setMonarchTokensProvider('sample', {
    ignoreCase:true,
    tokenizer: {
        root: [
            [/cmd1|cmd2/, 'keyword']
        ]
    }
});

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    value: "cmd1 10\nCMD2 10",
    language: 'sample'
});
```